# MLT / melt: concatenate clips, fade-in/fade-out audio and video

Tags: command-line-interface, mlt, melt-framework

I am attempting to automate a mundane video-editing task that I perform on a weekly basis. I would like to use `melt` to do this.

Assume that I have videos `a`, `b`, and `c`. I would like to do the following:

1. Snip `a1`, `b1`, and `c1` from within `a`, `b`, and `c`.
2. Concatenate `a1`, `b1`, and `c1` into a single video.
3. Fade to/from black for one second when transitioning between `a1`, `b1`, and `c1`.
4. Apply a soundtrack to the concatenated output of `a1`, `b1`, and `c1`, while also preserving the original audio.
5. Fade out the soundtrack as `c1` fades to black (concluding the video).

Whereby:

1. `a`, `b`, and `c` are of an arbitrary length.
2. `a`, `b`, and `c` are all 1080p videos filmed at 60 frames per second.
3. `a`, `b`, `c`, `a1`, `b1`, and `c1` are all `.mp4` files.
4. The soundtrack is an `.mp3` file.

This is as close as I have gotten:

```
#!/bin/sh
melt \
  colour:black out=59 $VIDEO1 in=0 out=600 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 $VIDEO2 in=0 out=600 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 $VIDEO3 in=0 out=600 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  -audio-track $AUDIO -transition mix
```

(I'm using arbitrary placeholders for the relevant files and fade-in/out times in the example above.)

This succeeds in snipping and concatenating `a1`, `b1`, and `c1` with animated transitions. However:

1. If `$AUDIO` is longer than the concatenation of `a1`, `b1`, and `c1`, the audio continues to play (with a white screen) after the video has ended.
2. The soundtrack does not fade out when `c1` fades out (ie, when the video is over).

From what I've gathered, fading out the soundtrack may be accomplished by "animating the volume audio filter", but I have had no success in attempting that.

What should I try?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For #1, you need to set an out point for the audio. You have three 601 frame clips (the zeroth frame counts as one) for a total of 1803 frames. So set out=1802.

For #2, you can apply the volume filter to the end of the audio track to make it fade out.

See the documentation for the volume filter to understand the gain and end parameters:
https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/FilterVolume/

```
#!/bin/sh
melt \
  colour:black out=59 $VIDEO1 in=0 out=600 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 $VIDEO2 in=0 out=600 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 $VIDEO3 in=0 out=600 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  colour:black out=59 -mix 60 -mixer luma \
  -audio-track $AUDIO out=1802 -attach-track volume:0db end=-70db in=1703 out=1802 \
  -transition mix in=0 out=1802
```

Comment: So this resolves item #1 (ending the audio when the video ends), so thanks for that! For some reason, though, it doesn't seem to fade out the audio (#2) when the movie ends. The documentation you linked suggests that it *should* work, though, so I'm unclear why it doesn't :/

I'll keep digging through the docs, and will post the answer here if I get this to work.

Comment: As I think about it, "mix" may not do what you want because it is really a crossfade and it applies a linear transition, not logarithmic. Maybe try applying the "volume" filter as suggested in my updated answer.

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for, and satisfies all of the goals stated in my question. Thanks so much for your help! (As soon as SO allows me, I'm going to award a 100 point bounty on your answer as thanks, for what that's worth.)